# Mouse Tracking in p5js

Tags: p5.js

I want something to happen in p5js when the mouse is over a map of a country (which is not a standard shape). How can I do that? I mean how can I track a mouse on a non-standard shape like the map of a country?

(I've loaded this shape as an image and the spots out of the borders are still part of the image but are transparent. )

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this:

- You could get the geometry in your code, and use that to check whether the cursor is inside the shape. Then google something like "check if point is inside polygon" for a ton of resources. You can do this even if you still want to use an image, or you could draw the shape using the `createShape()` method instead.
- Or you could check the color under the mouse. If it's not the background color, then you're inside the shape. This will only work if you only have one country, or if every country is a different color.

If I were you, I would lean towards the first option. Get something simple working first: create a hard-coded shape, and then create a sketch that prints a message to the console when the mouse clicks inside that shape. Then get the geometry for the country and use that instead of the hard-coded shape.

Then if you get stuck, you can post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with a more specific technical question. Good luck.

Comment: Actually I'm already doing this but since it is a country map, it has lots of lefts and rights, ups an downs you know. So it's almost impossible to get the exact geometry of the map so we can make something happen using an 'if' statement for instance.

Comment: @Ata You're probably going to want to write a separate function that checks whether the mouse is in a particular country. That function would take one of the approaches I outlined above, and you'd then call that function from your `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than going through effort to track the mouse and perform your own colission-detection, why not go old-school and use `<map>` and `<area>`?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area

> The HTML `<area>` element defines a hot-spot region on an image, and optionally associates it with a hypertext link. This element is used only within a `<map>` element.
>
> The HTML `<map>` element is used with  elements to define an image map (a clickable link area).

`<area>` is represented in the DOM by `HTMLAreaElement` which implements the `HTMLElement` interface so you can listen to `mouseover` events coming from the `<area>` elements:

Example HTML (from the MDN article):

```
<map name="infographic" id="myInfographic">
    <area shape="rect" coords="184,6,253,27"
      href="https://mozilla.org"
      target="_blank" alt="Mozilla" />
    <area shape="circle" coords="130,136,60"
      href="https://developer.mozilla.org/"
      target="_blank" alt="MDN" />
    <area shape="poly" coords="130,6,253,96,223,106,130,39"
      href="https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Guide/Graphics"
      target="_blank" alt="Graphics" />
    <area shape="poly" coords="253,96,207,241,189,217,223,103"
      href="https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML"
      target="_blank" alt="HTML" />
    <area shape="poly" coords="207,241,54,241,72,217,189,217"
      href="https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript"
      target="_blank" alt="JavaScript" />
    <area shape="poly" coords="54,241,6,97,36,107,72,217"
      href="https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API"
      target="_blank" alt="Web APIs" />
    <area shape="poly" coords="6,97,130,6,130,39,36,107"
      href="https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS"
      target="_blank" alt="CSS" />
</map>
<img usemap="#infographic" src="/media/examples/mdn-info.png" alt="MDN infographic" />
```

Script:

```
var areas = document.querySelectorAll( '#myInfographic area' );
for( var i = 0; i < areas.length; i++ ) {
    areas[i].addEventListener( 'mouseover', function( e ) {
        console.log( 'over some area' );
    } );
}
```